Phone Verfication Auth is not allowing to Access data in Firestore
I am facing issue with Getting Data from Firestore

Error : FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

After changing the rule to below
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Below is the Function from where i am trying to Call the database
async handelSearch(searchTerm: any) {

  onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, see the user's uid
      console.log(user.uid)
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      let temp: any[] = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        temp.push(doc.data())
      });
      this.serachBarService.MemberList.update(() => temp);


      // Access and modify user data here
    } else {
      console.log("No auth")
      // User is signed out
    }
  });
}

I am successfully able to console log the User ID also Authentication seems working fine to me don't know what's missing while accessing the firestore.
I am working with Highly sensitive data here so can't run database in Test mode
UPDATE :
I tested this in Emulator, Rule is working correctly there


I found the issue. App Check was enforced on Firestore. After disabling it, the problem was resolved. I'm unsure why App Check was blocking reads and writes
However, I verified that my security rules were functioning correctly, allowing only authenticated users to read and write.

"I'm unsure why App Check was blocking reads and writes" If App Check enforcement is enabled and your access is rejected because of that, it stands to reason that you didn't implement the client for that (correctly). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider for step-by-step instructions.

Thanks @puf-FrankvanPuffelen, Will check on this..
